# Keep reading lines from socket and save them

Tags: php, sockets

What I am trying to achieve is to read from a socket, line by line, and save them to a text file.

I have used socket_recv and socket_read. I can view the output on a page but when I save the output, its garbage. Filled with string and garbage binary stuff.

I know why it is because of the length of receiving data. But there is no way to know how much I will receive.

I used a example from the web

```
$str = "";
        while($read = socket_read($sock, 3,PHP_NORMAL_READ)) {
   $str .= $read;
   if (strpos($str, "\n") !== false) break;  // this stops the loop when a new line is encountered, how to restart the loop and read the rest of the lines
}

echo "Server said: $str";

//echo $this->_buffer;
$output = $str;
//echo "This much bytes ".strlen($this->_buffer);
        $file = 'log.txt';
                $handle = fopen($file,"a") or die("Could not open file for writing");
                fwrite($handle,$output) or die("Could not write");
                fclose($handle);
```

This snippet will save one line to a text file, but I have around 3 lines to receive.

How can I make this loop read all the receiving lines and write them to a text file.

Comment: if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg  = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
  }

  if (!socket_connect($sock, $this->_ip, $this->_port)) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg  = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
  }

Comment: When continue is added instead of break. I am getting socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: It is a small server coded in C. The php script send a command to retrieve Apache error log. I specify the amount of line and conditions i.e log time etc. From the browser i can get 3 lines if i want to. But the saving to text part, i am bogged down. Should i post the C code?